# Managing the static counter variable of each object

Tags: c++

I want to count ascending and descending data for each created object.But I can't handle it separately because the 2 objects I created also use the same static variable.The codes are as follows, How do I have to make changes.

```
void MyObject::handle_receive(std::size_t length) {

    getIncrementCount()++;
    if(some-condition)
    {
        getIncrementCount() = 0;
        getDecreaseCount() = 0;

    }

}

void MyObject::handle_timeout() {

    getDecreaseCount()++;
    if(some-condition)
    {
        getIncrementCount() = 0;
        getDecreaseCount() = 0;

    }

}

int & MyObject::getDecreaseCount()
{
    static int theCount = 0;
    return theCount;
}

int & MyObject::getIncrementCount()
{
    static int theCount = 0;
    return theCount;
}

main()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SensorSettingsList.size(); i++) {
        try {
            MyObject *ipPingReporter = new MyObject(io_service, SensorSettingsList.at(i).biosName);
        }
        catch (std::exception& e) {
            std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please revisit the meaning of `static`. It is *exactly* the opposite of what you want - it is a variable that is *shared* between all objects of the same type.

For keeping state in an object, you need to make the variable part of the class, not of the function:

```cpp
class MyObject {
  int incrementCount;

  void increment() {
    ++incrementCount;
  }

  int getIncrementCount() {
    return incrementCount;
  }
};
```

(I implemented the methods within the class for brevity. You can continue to implement them in `void MyObject::increment`, which is arguably better.)

Other than that (somewhat unrelated to your question), I would suggest that you do not return references to those variables. You do not want an outside class to modify the value. Right now, in your code, there is nothing that keeps me from messing up the counts by calling `someObject.getIncrementCount() = 15`.